# Problem with accessing nested childs in SOAP XML response in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

s2 = """<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2020-11-19T19:01:30.066Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2020-11-19T19:06:30.066Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetStatusOfTicketResponse xmlns="https://pl" 
        xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Domain.Beans.Tickets"
         xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Ticket>DodajKarty_101</a:Ticket>
            <a:InfoStatus>
                <Code>05300001</Code>
                <Message>Podany ticket nie istnieje w systemie</Message>
                <Status>ERROR</Status>
            </a:InfoStatus>
        </GetStatusOfTicketResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(s2)
print(tree)
print("tag: ", tree.tag)
print('attrib: ', tree.attrib)


ns = {'a': "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Domain.Beans.Tickets"}

print("Ticket: ", tree.find('.//{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Domain.Beans.Tickets}Ticket').text)
#Ticket:  DodajKarty_101 #Is accessible
```

But when I want to access this part:

```
        <a:Ticket>DodajKarty_101</a:Ticket>
            <a:InfoStatus>
                <Code>05300001</Code>
                <Message>Podany ticket nie istnieje w systemie</Message>
                <Status>ERROR</Status>
            </a:InfoStatus>
        </GetStatusOfTicketResponse>

print("InfoStatus: ", tree.find('.//{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Webservice.Domain.Beans.Tickets}InfoStatus').text)
print("Message: ", tree.find('.//a:InfoStatus', ns).text)
print("InfoStatus: ", tree.find('.//InfoStatus').text)
print("Code: ", tree.find('.//InfoStatus/Code').text)
```

I'm stuck on error. I'd looked for examples in doc https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html and they are working on my machine. But when I try to apply this knowledge on my XML I'm falling to extract 'Code', 'Message', and 'Status'.

I have no problem when I use another package to parse XML like xmltodict, but my next goal is to put a new child in XML to create new responses, so I need to solve this problem with xml.etree

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\addingChildsToXML.py", line 43, in <module>
    print("InfoStatus: ", tree.find('.//InfoStatus').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways to handle this, so here's one:

```
ticket = tree.xpath('//a:Ticket',namespaces=ns)[0]
print("Ticket: ", ticket.text)
status = ticket.xpath('//*[local-name()="InfoStatus"]//*')
for s, t in zip(["Code","Message","Status"],status):
    print(s,": ",t.text)
```

Output:

```
Ticket:  DodajKarty_101
Code :  05300001
Message :  Podany ticket nie istnieje w systemie
Status :  ERROR
```

Comment: Hey after running:  ticket = tree.xpath('//a:Ticket',namespaces=ns)[0]    
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'xpath'

Comment: @M.Siwik Sorry didn't notice you' aren't using lxml. Try changing your import statement to `from lxml import etree as ET` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Ok, now it's working, but I have follow up question. status = ticket.xpath('//*[local-name()="InfoStatus"]//*') this live give's me list. How to access in that way xpath specifically of for example 'Code'?

Comment: What would be xpath for 'Code'

Comment: @M.Siwik One way to handle it: `ticket.xpath('//*[local-name()="InfoStatus"]//*[local-name()="Code"]')[0]`